# Use cases for Hermitian matrix representation of 4D Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states

Two possible representations of the four-dimensional Hilbert space are the 4D column vectors or the 2x2 Hermitian matrices. For example, consider the two following representations of an orthonormal basis:

$$\underbrace{\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}}_\text{4D column vector representation}\quad\text{and}\quad\underbrace{\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{bmatrix},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right\}}_{2\times2\text{ Hermitian matrix representation}}$$

Where an appropriate inner product for the matrix representation can be shown to be defined by $\langle \boldsymbol A|\boldsymbol B\rangle\equiv\operatorname{tr}\left(\boldsymbol A^\dagger\boldsymbol B\right)$.

I was wondering whether there are any situations where it would be helpful or be more intuitive to represent the state kets as matrices such as above?

To clarify, I know that we often write states as density matrices ($|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ - example pure state) to allow for mixed states. I am not interested in this but interested in matrix representations of kets.

Comment: For two qubits, the [Schmidt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition) of a n entangled state corresponds to the SVD of the 2x2 matrix representation described. This question feels like its going to end up as a 'big list' question though which are discouraged.

Comment: I think that there are many situations where it would be helpful or be more intuitive to represent the states as matrices. It's helpful in cases of product states $\:\boldsymbol{\xi}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{\eta}\:$ where $\:\boldsymbol{\xi}\in \mathrm H_\alpha, \boldsymbol{\eta}\in \mathrm H_\beta\:$ and very convenient if the Hilbert spaces $\: \mathrm H_\alpha, \mathrm H_\beta\:$ are of the same dimension since then the matrices are square (1)...

Comment: @jacob1729 Thank you for the link I will have a read later when I get some time! In regards to the 'big lists' being discouraged is that questions that incite them or answers of that form? If it is questions I apologise and will close my question.

Comment: ...(1) See here [How to understand the makeup of neutral pi and eta mesons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484817/how-to-understand-the-makeup-of-neutral-pi-and-eta-mesons/485086#485086) how the states of mesons of three quarks $\:\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{d},\boldsymbol{s}\:$ are represented by $\:3\times 3\:$ matrices in equation (009). Also note that the inner product in the product Hilbert space of two states $\:\mathrm{X},\mathrm{Y}\:$  is represented by the trace $\:\langle \mathrm{X},\mathrm{Y}\rangle =\mathrm{Tr}\left[\mathrm{X}\mathrm{Y}^{*}\right]\:$ (2)...

Comment: ...(2) in equation (016) in agreement to your definition.

Comment: In my **S E C O N D___ A N S W E R** here [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156) you could see the representation of product states $\:\boldsymbol{\xi}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{\eta}\:$ in general, see equation (19). Usually we $''$arrange$''$ the matrix in a column matrix according to the scheme under this equation and described by equations (20a,b,c)...(3)

Comment: (3)... Only under this $''$arrangement$''$ the product of two transformations $\:\mathrm{A}\boldsymbol{\otimes} \mathrm{B}\:$ is represented conveniently by a matrix as provided by equation (47) in my **T H I R D___ A N S W E R**.

Comment: Thank you, very comprehensive @Frobenius

Comment: @Chris Long : Welcome, Chris. The 25 days membership, the 21 very good answers make me suspect that you will grow up to a "terrible" user herein PSE. Good Luck.