# Particles composed of square roots?

Tags: hilbert-space, standard-model, superposition, quarks, mesons

There are some particles which require square roots when telling their compositions. Mostly mesons, not baryons.

e.g. $$ρ^0=\frac{u\bar{u}-d\bar{d}}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Could you explain me how to make sense of it?

Comment: This is just a convention for normalization of particles in Quantum Field Theory

Comment: Related : **(1)** [How to understand the makeup of neutral pi and eta mesons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/484817/how-to-understand-the-makeup-of-neutral-pi-and-eta-mesons/485086#485086). **(2)** [What is the symmetry of the pion triplet (π−,π0,π+)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420080/what-is-the-symmetry-of-the-pion-triplet-pi-pi0-pi).

Comment: Oh thank you for letting me know!

Comment: As a general suggestion: unless you specify at which level you are expecting the answer to your question to be, we'll usually assume people asking about Particle Physics to be quite acquainted with Quantum Mechanics, Relativity, and so on. From your other question, this doesn't seem to be the case, so I suggest always making explicit in your questions what we could assume that you know when we answer

Comment: (This is the subject of [a meta question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13954/).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some particles which are made of a specific composition of quarks and are always made of that composition. For example, as I believe you have heard of, protons and neutrons are always composed of $uud$ and $udd$, respectively.

You can think of this intuitively in the following sense: if you could pick up a proton and look inside it to figure out what it is made of, you would have $100\%$ probability to find $uud$ inside it. Similarly, if you were to pick up a neutron and look inside it, you would always find $udd$ inside it.

This seems a silly way of putting it, perhaps even obvious. They are made like that, what else could happen? Why am I stating what they are made of in terms of probabilities?

Let us consider a different particle then. For example, the $\rho^0$ meson you mentioned. This guy works different: as you noticed, it is composed of a difference of quarks (what is that?) and has that weird square root. What do these things mean?

The tricky bit is that the $\rho^0$ is in a superposition of states (see, e.g., the [Wikipedia page on superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition) or the [Simple English Wikipedia page on Quantum Mechanics](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics)). To keep it simple, I'll break one of my personal rules of never talking about [Schrödinger's cat](https://youtu.be/IOYyCHGWJq4) and say it is quite similar: if you were to pick up the $\rho^0$ meson and look inside it, there is a $50\%$ chance you will find $u\bar{u}$ and a $50\%$ chance you'll find $d\bar{d}$. It is in a quantum superposition! The minus sign indices that the meson is a superposition of the states $u\bar{u}$ and $d\bar{d}$, and the $\sqrt{2}$ is chosen to ensure the probabilities add to $100\%$ (the rough idea to compute the probabilities is by taking the number in front of the possibility you want to consider and taking its [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) squared).

It is worth mentioning that the minus sign does have some other implications, and if we changed it to a plus sign it wouldn't be a $\rho^0$ meson, but an [$\omega$ meson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_meson) instead.

In short, the presence of the square roots are just to ensure the sum of all the probabilities are $100\%$. Some particles have well-defined constituents, but some others are superpositions of different possibilities.

Comment: In another question you mentioned you are young and are not that used to physics, so I have tried to keep the answer as simple as possible (while still using the knowledge you seem to have). If at any point I used any words you are not familiar with and I do not explain them nor pointed a link discussing them, feel free to ask for clarification. If the links are useless, feel free to ask for clarification as well.

Comment: Also, since I tried to keep the language simple, had to sacrifice a bit of precision. [Particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_physics) is a subject that can be understood with effort and time, but it is quite complicated to explain the main ideas in full precision in a short time.

Comment: Thank you for telling things simple. I'll have to learn more particle physics!

Comment: @MangoMochi You're welcome! If the answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).